# Does the clear() method empty value referenced by the Object?

Tags: java, json, object

Does the `clear()` method empty the value referenced by the JSON Object ?

For example :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject objtemp = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
String[] details;
for (int i = 0; i < tempvals.length; ++i) {
  objtemp.clear();
  details = tempvals[i].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
  objtemp.put("inspectionDate", details[7]);
  objtemp.put("code", details[9]);
  objtemp.put("description", details[10]);
  objtemp.put("score", details[12]);
  objtemp.put("grade", details[13]);
  objtemp.put("gradeDate", details[14]);
  arr.add(objtemp);
}
obj.put("violationDetails", arr);
arr.clear();
```

The above object `obj` is null after executing the above code. My purpose of using the clear method is to prevent the creation of new objects at each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it clears the reference. You only have one reference. You then clear it, and add data to it (but you only have one instance). You need something like

```
// JSONObject objtemp = new JSONObject();
for (int i = 0; i < tempvals.length; ++i) {
  // objtemp.clear(); // <-- only one objtemp.
  JSONObject objtemp = new JSONObject();
  details = tempvals[i].split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");
  objtemp.put("inspectionDate", details[7]);
  objtemp.put("code", details[9]);
  objtemp.put("description", details[10]);
  objtemp.put("score", details[12]);
  objtemp.put("grade", details[13]);
  objtemp.put("gradeDate", details[14]);
  arr.add(objtemp);
}
obj.put("violationDetails", arr);
// arr.clear(); // <-- would empty arr in `obj`.
```

Comment: So at each iteration of the for loop, the `objtemp` will reference to a new memory location ? When I do `arr.add(objtemp)`, I am basically storing the reference to the `JSONArray`.

Comment: @Viraj Technically yes, that's what `new` does. Don't call `arr.clear()` or `obj` will contain an empty `violationDetails` (for example).

Comment: Okay. I am basically running out of Java Heap Space in eclipse so was trying to find ways to minimize my memory usage.